# Make a TextBlock wrap inside Grid Column

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML which shows a textblock in a grid. The problem is that it just stretches out, it even stretches itself greater than the windows width.

```
<Grid Background="Gray">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Padding="0" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,0,5,0">Description:</Label>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to `restrict the width` of the second column to make the text wrap -

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: Thanks, your example works. It turns out my question was wrong, the real problem is DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate and then this content inside it. Perhaps you'll be able to answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518476/make-textblock-wrap-in-datagrid-rowdetailstemplate

Comment: Page not available for the question you posted.